# Конвертировать GSON в объект с дополнительным полем

Tags: java, json, gson

Есть у меня JSON файл:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "Title",
      "description": "Description"
    },
    {
      "title": "Title",
      "description": "Description"
    }
  ]
}
```

И есть Java класс:

```
public class {
    lond id;
    String title;
    String description;
}
```

В конструкторе класса id генерируется сам. 
Как преобразовать JSON файл с помощью GSON чтобы id генерировался автоматически?

Comment: Конструктор, в котором генерируется `id`, имеет аргументы?

Comment: да, title и description в качестве аргументов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотеки вроде **Gson**, **Jackson** и т.д. при десериализации вызывают `default-конструктор` (без параметров), после с использованием рефлексии заполняются поля объекта класса

Если вы хотите, чтоб в процессе десериализации из **JSON** в объект класса у этого объекта определять какое-то поле, то делайте это в `default-конструкторе`

Comment: Благодарю. Это помогло)